# Handling login session of facebook sdk in android

Tags: java, android, facebook, import

Currently I use the latest sdk to implement facebook login, however, it is slightly different from the actual behavior of the offical one

**The official behavior:** user click on the login button , the permission dialog prompt , if I click cancel, it will close the box, it will login only when I click confirm

**My app behavior:** user click on the login button , the permission dialog prompt , if I click cancel, it will close the box, but if I click the login button again , it will not show any permission dialog, and will login

I have copied the code from the offical sample so I am confused why it behave differently in my app. How to fix it? Thanks

Facebook sample (I use the offical code to build my login button)

```
public class SessionLoginFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String URL_PREFIX_FRIENDS = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=";

    private TextView textInstructionsOrLink;
    private Button buttonLoginLogout;
    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

        buttonLoginLogout = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonLoginLogout);
        textInstructionsOrLink = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.instructionsOrLink);

        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(getActivity(), null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(getActivity());
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
            }
        }

        updateView();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    private void updateView() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            textInstructionsOrLink.setText(URL_PREFIX_FRIENDS + session.getAccessToken());
            buttonLoginLogout.setText(R.string.logout);
            buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogout(); }
            });
        } else {
            textInstructionsOrLink.setText(R.string.instructions);
            buttonLoginLogout.setText(R.string.login);
            buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogin(); }
            });
        }
    }

    private void onClickLogin() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }

    private void onClickLogout() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isClosed()) {
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        }
    }

    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            updateView();
        }
    }
}
```

My app (I used the same method name of the offical one, I haven't add additional code for facebook login)

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements LoginListener {
    private final static String TAG = "Home";
    public View rootView;
    public ImageView HomeBg;
    public ImageView buttonLoginLogout;
    public TextView chi;
    public TextView eng;
    public ColorStateList oldColor;
    public SharedPreferences prefs;
    public EasyTracker tracker = null;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public ArrayList<String> permission;
    public ProgressDialog pd;
    public Home ctx;

    //Facebook login
    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        ctx = this;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        try{
            // fix for disable the hiding action bar animation
            getActivity().getActionBar().getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setShowHideAnimationEnabled", boolean.class).invoke(getActivity().getActionBar(), false);
        } catch (Exception exception){
            // animation will be run if not support
        }

        getActivity().getActionBar().hide();

        tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity());

        if (permission == null) {
            permission = new ArrayList<String>();
            permission.add("email");
        }

        prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("userInfo", 0);
        editor = prefs.edit();

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        buttonLoginLogout = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_connectFB);
        eng = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_eng);
        chi = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_chi);

        eng.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (!Utility.getLocale(getActivity()).equals("en")) {
                    tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("menu_click","language", "switchEN", null).build());
                    chi.setTextColor(oldColor);
                    eng.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                    MyApp.updateLanguage(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "en");
                    refreshAfterLocaleChanged("en");
                }
            }
        });

        chi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (!Utility.getLocale(getActivity()).equals("zh")) {
                    tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("menu_click","language", "switchTC", null).build());
                    eng.setTextColor(oldColor);
                    chi.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                    MyApp.updateLanguage(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "zh");
                    refreshAfterLocaleChanged("zh");
                }
            }
        });

        if (Utility.getLocale(getActivity()).equals("zh")) {
            chi.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(
                    android.R.color.white));
            oldColor = eng.getTextColors();
        } else {
            eng.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(
                    android.R.color.white));
            oldColor = chi.getTextColors();

        }

        //Facebook login
        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(getActivity(), null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(getActivity());
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
            }
        }

       updateView();

       return rootView;
    }

    public void refreshAfterLocaleChanged(String lang){
        SharedPreferences langPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        Editor editor = langPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString("lang",lang).commit();

        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        getActivity().finish();
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
        tracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "hk7app/CX/" + Utility.getLocale(getActivity()) + "/Landing Page");
        tracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (pd != null)
            pd.dismiss();

        Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
        EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity()).activityStop(getActivity());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void updateView() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session.isOpened()) {
             final String token = session.getAccessToken();
             Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,Response response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (user != null) {
                            if (!user.getId().equals(prefs.getString("fbId",""))) {
                                editor.putString("fbId", user.getId());
                                editor.putString("fName", user.getFirstName());
                                editor.putString("lName", user.getLastName());
                                editor.putString("email", user.asMap().get("email").toString());
                                editor.commit();
                            }
                            if (prefs.getString("memId","").equals("") || prefs.getString("token","").equals("") || !user.getId().equals(prefs.getString("fbId",""))){
                                pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.sys_info),getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
                                new APIHandler(getActivity(),tracker,"login",pd).execute(ctx,token);
                            } else {
                                onLoginComplete("","");
                            }
                        }
                    }
             });                  
        } else {
            buttonLoginLogout.setImageResource(R.drawable.landing_btn_connect_facebook);
            buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogin(); }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    private void onClickLogin() {
        tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("menu_click","Fbconnect","connectFB_" + Utility.getLocale(getActivity()),null).build());
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }

    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            Log.d(TAG,"SessionStatusCallback");
            if (exception != null) {
                Log.d(TAG,""+exception);

                if (!session.isClosed())
                    session.closeAndClearTokenInformation(); //reset session

                if (exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException){
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.sys_info))
                    .setMessage(R.string.facebook_permission_missing)
                    .setPositiveButton(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.close), null)
                    .show();
                }
            } else {
                updateView();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getActivity(),getResources().getString(R.string.app_id));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginComplete(String memberId, String token) {    
        if (pd != null)
            pd.dismiss();

        if (!memberId.equals("") && !token.equals("")) {
            editor.putString("memId", memberId);
            editor.putString("token", token);
            editor.commit();
        }

        buttonLoginLogout.setImageResource(R.drawable.landing_btn_take_a_selfie);
        buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("menu_click","TakeSelfie","Selfie_now_" + Utility.getLocale(getActivity()),null).build());
                ((LandingPage)getActivity()).tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginFailure(String errorMsg) {
        if (pd != null)
            pd.dismiss();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: What does your AndroidManifest.xml look like? Which permissions have you requested there?

Comment: Which error do you get? Where the code stop working?

Comment: If you cancel login without granting access, and click login again, it will open permission page again. In order to login use, the user should accept permission dialog

Comment: On the next login, you must remove the permission scopes if any(in your case 'email') and then only it will allow to login without persmissions page. Also, you won't get details of the user profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public class FbActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final String PERMISSION = "publish_actions";


private final String PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY = "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook:PendingAction";

private LoginButton loginButton;
private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
private TextView greeting;
private PendingAction pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
private ViewGroup controlsContainer;
private GraphUser user;
private GraphPlace place;
private List<GraphUser> tags;
private boolean canPresentShareDialog;


private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private FacebookDialog.Callback dialogCallback = new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall,
            Exception error, Bundle data) {
        Log.d("HelloFacebook", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall,
            Bundle data) {
        Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Success!");
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        String name = savedInstanceState
                .getString(PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY);
        pendingAction = PendingAction.valueOf(name);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fb);


    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton
            .setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                    FbActivity.this.user = user;

                    onClickPostPhoto();

                    updateUI();
                    // It's possible that we were waiting for this.user to
                    // be populated in order to post a
                    // status update.
                    handlePendingAction();
                }
            });

    profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
    greeting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greeting);

    controlsContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_ui_container);

    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if (fragment != null) {
        // If we're being re-created and have a fragment, we need to a) hide
        // the main UI controls and
        // b) hook up its listeners again.
        controlsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    // Listen for changes in the back stack so we know if a fragment got
    // popped off because the user
    // clicked the back button.
    fm.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                // We need to re-show our UI.
                controlsContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    canPresentShareDialog = FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(this,
            FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();

    // Call the 'activateApp' method to log an app event for use in
    // analytics and advertising reporting. Do so in
    // the onResume methods of the primary Activities that an app may be
    // launched into.
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

    updateUI();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putString(PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingAction.name());
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, dialogCallback);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {
    if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE
            && (exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException || exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException)) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(FbActivity.this)
                .setTitle(R.string.cancelled)
                .setMessage(R.string.permission_not_granted)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null).show();
        pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
    } else if (state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {
        handlePendingAction();
    }
    updateUI();
}

private void updateUI() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    boolean enableButtons = (session != null && session.isOpened());

    if (enableButtons && user != null) {
        profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
        greeting.setText(user.getFirstName());

    } else {
        profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);
        greeting.setText(null);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("incomplete-switch")
private void handlePendingAction() {
    PendingAction previouslyPendingAction = pendingAction;
    // These actions may re-set pendingAction if they are still pending, but
    // we assume they
    // will succeed.
    pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
    // pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_PHOTO;

}

private interface GraphObjectWithId extends GraphObject {
    String getId();
}
}
```